# DatePicker crashes when showing a Fragment

Tags: android, datepicker, illegalstateexception

I'm trying to use date picker widget out of the docs example here:
[docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)

However when i call newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

application crashes and stack trace shows the following:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.wgu.andrey.clp1, PID: 8125
                                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1864)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:650)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:609)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:143)
                                                                   at com.wgu.andrey.clp1.Terms.showDatePickerDialog(Terms.java:67)
```

DatePickerFragment.java

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
}
```

}

Terms.java

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are calling `show()` from the main thread? (UI thread). Also, extend `FragmentActivity` and not `Activity`.

Comment: Please post your code for onCreateDialog method and the method where you are calling newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

Comment: @Sevastyan I'm extending MainActivity, which extends AppCompatActivity. I need that for some navigation bars to work.

Comment: How exactly are you calling `showDatePickerDialog()`? Is `Terms` the currently running `Activity`? Or is it some sort of helper/utility class?

Comment: @MikeM. Terms is a utility class

Comment: OK, you can't instantiate an `Activity` subclass with `new` and have it work correctly, which is why you're getting that Exception. `Terms` should not extend an `Activity` unless it is being used as an `Activity`.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks Mike, i moved the code to the main activity class an it worked like a charm. However I'm stumped now over hiding a keyboard issue

Comment: I wonder View parameter is never used in showDatePickerDialog then why can't I remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the same lines what @Mike said, terms class can't be a sub class of the activity. Move the method to its own utility class and then call that method by Either passing the context or passing the fragment manager.

Something like this:

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v, AppCompatActivity context) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DialogFragment();
        newFragment.show(context.getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAG");
}
```

Alternatively, using `FragmentManager`

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v, FragmentManager fm) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DialogFragment();
        newFragment.show(fm, "datePicker");
}
```

Comment: in that case how do you call the method? I mean to ask what parameters will you pass?